# Want to include only some fields of an object that are being mapped to JSON by Genson

Tags: json, genson

My Pojo class contains 50 fields and I need to convert only 10 fields to json.

```
Genson genson = new Genson.Builder().include("address4", User.class).create();
String json = genson.serialize(user);
```

"include()" method doesn't seem to be working. Kindly help.

Comment: found a solution for the question. First exclude all using the data type and include only required field. Genson genson = new Genson.Builder().exclude(String.class).exclude(Integer.class).include("address4", User.class).create();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Genson genson = new Genson.Builder()
                 .exclude(Object.class)//this excludes all object types
                 .include("address4", User.class).create();//then add only required fields
String json = genson.serialize(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to disable by default all properties and include selectively those you want like this:

```
new GensonBuilder()
  .useFields(false)
  .useMethods(false)
  .include("address4", User.class)
  .create();
```

Note that I think you can also use `@JsonProperty` annotation on the fields you want to include instead of including them via the GensonBuilder.

If you are feeling your self of contributing to the lib, you could also improve the [PropertyFilter class](https://github.com/owlike/genson/blob/master/genson/src/main/java/com/owlike/genson/reflect/PropertyFilter.java) to support regular expressions for the field name or by adding another method that would be excludeAll(Class clazz)/includeAll(Class clazz), that would exclude all properties from this class. I opened [this issue](https://github.com/owlike/genson/issues/94) to track this feature.

Comment: I can not use @JsonProperty, because some fields are from parent class, which I don't have permission to make changes. And also new GensonBuilder()
  .exclude(Object.class) excludes all, instead of using each object type.

Comment: Oh yeah right, though I am not sure it excludes primitive types.

Comment: is it possible to maintain the order of fields in which we are including. ??

Comment: I am not sure to understand, do you have an example? Genson is writing the fields in alphabetical order - for the moment this is not configurable.

Comment: **{"address":"ADDRESS","name":"NAME","PHone":0,"id":101}**  right now it gives the result as above. But I want the result to be **{"id":101,"name":"NAME","address":"ADDRESS","PHone":0}** is it possible in Genson to get the result in custom order. ?

Comment: There is no public API to configure this yet, the order is hardcoded [here](https://github.com/owlike/genson/blob/master/genson/src/main/java/com/owlike/genson/reflect/BeanDescriptor.java#L68), feel free to open a PR for this or open an issue in the github project and it will be provided in a future release.